# How to slide in a div when you select a radio button with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am planning a following html output with PHP. Now when I select week, I want to slide in week div, selecting day,day div etc.

How can I do it with jquery.

```
<div id="main">
 <form>
<div id="week_day_time">

<input type="radio" name="week_day_time" value="week" />Week<br />
<input type="radio" name="week_day_time" value="day" />Day<br />
<input type="radio" name="week_day_time" value="time" />Time

</div>
<div id="week">
more form for week.
originally hidden by css. But it will open when you select a week radio button.
more form for week
</div>
<div id="day">
more form...
originally hidden by css. But it will open when you select a day radio button.
more form for day
</div>
<div id="time">
more form...
originally hidden by css. But it will open when you select a time radio button.
more form for time
</div>
</form> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var current = '';
$('[name="week_day_time"]').change(function() {
    if(current.length) 
        $('#' + current).slideUp();
    current = $(this).val();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown();
});
```

### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7VBJn/2/)

​

Comment: @shin, Oops, good catch. That was for the other solution that I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

I would do more or less the following:
http://jsfiddle.net/dactivo/dhwZY/

I would wrap the texts in a div called "texts", and exec the following function:

```
$('input[name="week_day_time"]').click(function() {

    $("#texts").children().slideUp();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown();

});
```

Comment: Once you wrap all the texts in one div, you can also slideUp everyone, like this:   $('#' + $(this).val()).siblings().slideUp();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown(); With this, there is no need for using any variables.